# Make the first row of an Excel chart be treated as a heading when it's a number?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

Given a data sample like

```
Prisoner    24601   0.50
Day 1   80  90
Day 2   81  89
Day 3   82  90
Day 4   81  91
```

What's the easiest way to tell Excel that 24601 and 0.50 are data series names rather than Y axis values when creating a line chart?

Approaches I'm aware of:

1. Turn Prisoner numbers into text by having ="24601" and ="0.50"
2. Only select rows 2 onwards as data, and then add in the labels once the graph has been created?

Approaches that don't appear to work:

1. Ask Excel to format the first row's numbers as text.

Comment: @linger I submitted an edit to remove the 'graphs' tag because it's deprecated. See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6841/should-charts-and-graphs-tags-be-merged.

Comment: @moses I submitted an edit to remove the 'graphs' tag because it's deprecated. See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6841/should-charts-and-graphs-tags-be-merged

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clear the top left cell. The blank cell tells Excel that the first row (series names) and first column (category labels) are special.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a ' (apostrophe) in front of the number? This should make the number a text, but still view it without the apostrophe, or is this approach on par with the ="1234" and not what you want?

Comment: You'd have to manually modify each cell, like approach 1 in the question, right?

Comment: It appears you have to, yes